# /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, sudo, sysfs, cpu-frequency

I was stuck when trying to write to a system file to change the cpu frequency:

```
$ cat   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
<unsupported>

$ echo 1600000 | sudo tee  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
1600000
tee: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed: Invalid argument
```

Changing user to root has the same problem:

```
$ sudo su
# echo 1600000 >   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

The following should probably be unrelated.
Previously, the above commands all worked, but then my Ubuntu was frozen an hour ago when I plug the usb plug of my laptop cooler into one usb port of my laptop, so I had to reboot it by hitting the power button of my laptop, and then I have the above problem.

Previously when it worked, `cat   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` output some value instead of `<unsupported>`. After trying many times with the above `invalid argument` error, now I just  ran `echo 1600000 | sudo tee  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` once again, and it works without the `invalid argument` error. Around the same time, ubuntu reported some cpu frequency utility error, which I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question. The problem is more than `sudo` and redirection.

Comment: Check and change the governor following the 2 tutos : [CPU frequency scaling in Linux with cpufreq](https://www.pantz.org/software/cpufreq/usingcpufreqonlinux.html) and [How to make use of Dynamic Frequency Scaling](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_Dynamic_Frequency_Scaling). Please check the current `scaling_governor` before making changes it can be the cause of the permission problem.

Answer (score 3):

The files in [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) and [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) are interfaces to the kernel. Reading and writing to these files invokes code in a driver in the kernel. If you get the error “permission denied” (EACCESS), that comes from the file permissions. But if you get an error such as “invalid argument” (EINVAL), it means the driver sent this reply.

The most obvious reason for “invalid argument” is that you're trying to write a value that isn't valid. For example, writing something that isn't a number to modify a numeric setting, or writing a number that's out of the acceptable range.

Given that reading returns the string `<unsupported>`, at that time on your machine, the driver thought that your hardware did not support this feature. Since it worked previously, this indicates either a bug in the driver or a hardware failure.

---

You've indicated that it now works again. So it was a transient problem that rebooting fixed. The rest of my answer is advice for people who have just been confronted with a similar problem.

If you upgraded your kernel recently, try reverting to the previous version.

Since the problem is in the kernel, or at least between the kernel or the hardware, you need to dig into the kernel logs to find more information. On a recent enough system with systemd, run `sudo journalctl -k` to see the kernel logs. Alternatively, look at `/var/log/kern*`, which includes older saved logs.

Finding the right log message can be difficult. If you can find the approximate time things started, look for log messages around that time. Try accessing the file in `/sys` now, this may or may not generate a new log message each time depending on how the driver works.

If you had some hardware related failure and rebooted, some firmware (software running on one of the auxiliary chips on the computer) may still have bad data. To completely reset all the firmware to its power-on state, you need to power the system down completely. On a laptop, sometimes it's even necessary to disconnect the power completely (take out the plug to the mains and the battery, then put them back).

Comment: Thanks. The problem just came back after I woke up Ubuntu from suspension. The problem  originally happened around the time when [I added running a script in either `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` when rebooting Ubuntu, but failed to do so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434740/674). I guess it is related. Besides your advice,  I was wondering if it is helpful to find out  which module is relevant, and unload and reload it?

Comment: @Tim This script doesn't seem relevant. It might fail due to the same problem but it's unlikely to cause the problem. Unloading and reloading a module might help, but it's more likely that it wouldn't help, and in your case I think the functionality is not in a module anyway.