# Shall I run a sudo-required script in some shell configuration file?

Tags: bash, sudo, configuration, etc

Is it a good idea to put a sudo command in a shell configuration file?

I have a bash script `/home/t/bin/changeCpuFreq.sh` which can change my cpu frequency. The line 40 in my script is

```
echo $1 >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
```

Which determines that running the script requires root privillege

I would like the script to run automatically every time I reboot Ubuntu or log in, and wonder where to put the command to run the script?

1. In `~/.profile`, I put

   ```
   sudo /home/t/bin/changeCpuFreq.sh 1600000
   ```

   When I reboot Ubuntu, after logging in, Ubuntu reports an error

   > Error found when loading `/home/t/profile`.
   >
   > sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified.
   >
   > As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
2. In `/etc/profile`, I put the following at the end:

   ```
   /home/t/bin/changeCpuFreq.sh 1600000
   ```

   When I reboot Ubuntu, I have an error before logging in:

   > Error found when loading `/etc/profile`:
   >
   > `/home/t/bin/changeCpuFreq.sh`: line 40
   >
   > `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed`: Permission denied
   >
   > As a result the session will not be configured correctly.

   Is it because I didn't set `sudo` up, and how shall I use `sudo`
   for a command in `/etc/profile`?

Thanks.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is never the right place to run a system-wide command on startup.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried `~/.profile`, and added `sudo`, but got the `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` error. I am confused.