# What's the purpose of using `sudo -S` explicitly?

Tags: sudo

From manpage of sudo:

> -S, --stdin
>
> Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the
>   standard input instead of using the terminal device. The password must
>   be followed by a newline character.

What is the purpose of using `sudo -S` instead of just `sudo`?

- Is it correct that`sudo` by default read password from standard input?
- What is the purpose of "Write the prompt to the standard error"? Does `sudo` by default write it to the standard output?
- Do they both require that the password must be followed by a newline character?

For example, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553081/156458, `sudo -S true` still requires typing in password, so how does it solve the original question in that post? I found that link when I searched for solution to [Shall I run a sudo-required script in some shell configuration file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434740/674)

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

The reply by J.Taylor said

> `sudo` does not read the password from stdin by default - it reads it from the terminal interface.

I was wondering how to understand it in terms of implementation.

Is it correct that when a program reads from standard input, it reads from  file descriptor 0 to which  the standard input is always binded?

Why can't I tell whether `sudo` uses standard input or terminal when using`sudo` without `-S`?

How can a program (such as `sudo -S`) achieve to read from terminal instead of standard input?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sudo` does *not* read the password from [stdin](http://www.linfo.org/stdio.html) by default - it reads it from the [terminal interface](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/). Using `sudo -S` allows you to pipe the password in from another command/file like this: `printf "yourpassword\n" | sudo -S nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

This could be used in a shell script to log in to sudo without being prompted for a password, but you need to be careful not to execute this kind of thing from the shell directly, because then your sudo password would be in the shell history.

Comment: Thanks. " it reads it from the terminal interface." But I always provide password to sudo from standard input. Isn't standard input connected to the terminal interface/emulator by default?

Comment: By default, yes it is. The point of -S is when you're overriding the default somehow, such as by piping to sudo.

Comment: @Joseph Usually a program accepts input from standard input (i.e. file descriptor 0). sudo doesn't do so. Does sudo open a fixed device file which represents the terminal?

Comment: For the password prompt, yes. For example, `echo abcd | sudo cat` will let you type the password, rather than using `abcd` as the password.

Comment: @JosephSible Thanks. (1) I was wondering what you meant by "For the password prompt, yes" ? (2) Why can't I tell if sudo uses standard input or terminal when using just `sudo`? How does a program use terminal instead of standard input?

Comment: (1) By default, sudo uses the terminal to read the password, and uses standard input to pass to the inner command's standard input. (2) This should be asked as a separate question, not just in a comment.