# Why does sudo accept password not from stdin by default?

Tags: sudo

I learned from my earlier question [What's the purpose of using `sudo -S` explicitly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/434759/674) that sudo accepts password not from stdin by default.

Why is that? Is it because of some security reason?

Answer (score 2):

It's often useful to pipe input into sudo, such as being able to do `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` without the 0 being interpreted as the sudo password. If sudo accepted the password from standard input, that wouldn't work.