# How can I pipe stdin inputs to command which expects multiple stdin inputs?

Tags: bash, pipe

1. ```
   yes mypassword |  while true; do sudo -S sleep 3; sudo -k; done
   ```

   can supply  multiple identical stdin inputs `mypassword` to  the
   while loop.
2. When [both `sudo -S` and the command it executes need different
   stdin input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479022/674), is there any way to provide their stdin inputs?

   ```
   <how can I supply password to sudo and "hello" to cat respectively> | sudo -S cat
   ```
3. More generally, if I know a command expects a number of different
   stdin inputs, how can I pipe the stdin inputs to it?

Thanks.

Comment: How about redirect the stdin of the inner command to the file you want?