# Why does my setup for no password prompt in /etc/sudoers not work?

Tags: sudo

My sudo version is

```
$ sudo --version
Sudo version 1.8.16
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.16
Sudoers file grammar version 45
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.16

$ which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo

$ whereis sudo
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/sudo /usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz
```

[I added a line to `/etc/sudoers` following the line for `root`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434842/674):

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# my change for scaling down cpu freq
t       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh
```

But after I reboot Ubuntu 16.04, I still need to provide password when running the script with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh  1600000
[sudo] password for t:
```

I was wondering why?

Note that in `/etc/sudoers`,

- I notice that the separator between `root` and `ALL` is a tab, and I also separate `t` and `ALL` with a tab, and the other separators are spaces. Originally I separated `t` and `ALL` with a few spaces, which didn't work. Does what the separator is matter?
- `/home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh` is pathname without any symlink, and originally, I tried a symlink, which didn't work. Does a symlink matter or not?

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

As the reply by steve suggested, I changed the line in `/etc/sudoers` to be

```
t       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh *
```

by adding `*` at the end, but it doesn't work.

Currently my `/etc/sudoers` looks like

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# my change for scaling down cpu freq
# t     ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh *
t ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh *

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The groups of `t` include `adm` (is `adm` same as `admin`?) and `sudo`:

```
$ groups t
t : t adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

The commands allowed to be run by `t` are:

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for t on ocean:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User t may run the following commands on ocean:
    (ALL : ALL) NOPASSWD:
        /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh *
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Comment: does user t belong to the `sudo` or the `admin` group?

Comment: just for clarity, could you also post the output of `sudo -l` when logged in as user "t" ?

Comment: @Rui Updated. Is `adm` same as`admin` group?

Comment: @steve: updated. indeed the script is listed.

Comment: @Tim: No, `admin` and `adm` are not the same.  You can tell because one of them has an `in` in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the argument, as @steve mentions, change the `ALL=(ALL)` for `ALL=(ALL:ALL)` as:

```
t ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh *
```

If the user t belongs to the sudo or admin group, you also have to put that line *after* the generic rules for the admin and sudo group. Per `man sudoers`, the last line contemplating a condition wins:

> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.
>   Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not
>   necessarily the most specific match).

Thus, if the more restrictive conditions are met on your now last line, the NOPASSWD directive will be applied, and then the password won't be asked anymore.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work. Does `(ALL:ALL)` mean all terminals and all target users, right?

Comment: see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918842

Comment: Thanks. Moving the new line to the end of the file works.

Comment: Is `adm` the same group as `admin`?

Comment: It is not the same... But t belongs to the sudo group, the %sudo line was taking precedence.

Comment: does `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` not imply that  all users in `sudo` group including `t` will be allowed execute all commands including my script as all users including root? So why do I need to add the new line to `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: You are creating a special case for it to happen without asking a password

Comment: What does `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` mean? I think it means that all users in `sudo` group (including user `t`) are allowed to execute all commands (including my script) as all users (including `root`)? So why do I need to create a special case for `t` and my script?

Comment: I think you are overlooking the  NOPASSWD directive

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the fact you're passing an argument is causing the issue.

Instead of:

```
t       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh
```

try this:

```
t       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/t/program_files/hardware/cpu/cpuFreq/changeCpuFreq.sh *
```

Comment: I could swear newer versions of `sudo` require the latter syntax.

Comment: Thanks. In `/etc/sudoers`, does using a pathname containing symlink(s) matter? Furthermore, when running the command via its symlink path with `sudo`, would there still be password prompt if the symlink is searched in the invoking user's `PATH`, e.g. `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" changeCpuFreq.sh 1600000`?

Comment: Also adding `*` doesn't work. See my update. I also added my sudo version.

Comment: Thanks. After moving the new line to the end of `/etc/sudoers`, it works both with and without `*`.

Comment: @Rui: Could you elaborate "newer versions of sudo require the latter syntax"?  My Sudo version is 1.8.16, and after moving the new line to the end of `/etc/sudoers`, it works both with and without `*`.

Comment: I had to add the * in several sudoers rules in a couple of servers that had rules for non-privileged users when I migrated my Debian infra-structure from Debian 8 to 9

Comment: @Rui Which version of sudo were you using?

Comment: Jessie 1.8.10, Stretch 1.8.19